# Why the value for f[i][j] would change when I set value to f[i-1][j]

Tags: python

Here is my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

m=1
n=1

f = [[0]*(m+1)]*(n+1)

for i in range (1, n+1):
    for j in range (0, m+1):

        f[i][j] = 101

        print "check 1: " + str(f[i][j])

        f[i-1][j] = 102

        print "check 2: " + str(f[i][j])
        print"\n"
```

The output I get:

```
check 1: 101
check 2: 102

check 1: 101
check 2: 102
```

While I'm changing the f[i-1][j], why the value for f[i][j] would change ?

Comment: You created a 2d list of references to the _same_ object `[0]`. When you you change it once, it "changes" everywhere.

Comment: Your problem is here `f = [[0]*(m+1)]*(n+1)` check out the link in @DYZ comment to know why

Comment: Thanks very much !